# How to set product attributes to basket line and order line in Oscar?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-oscar

I'm new to Django-oscar and working on Basket now I can add products as lines to the basket easily but what if I want to choose a specific Product attribute to add to basket for example product A has attributes {'size': ['M', 'S'], 'color': ['red', 'blue']} what should I do if I want to add product A with size M and the color blue to the basket?

Then I want to store and show the selected option attribute, (for example a customer choose product with color 'red' and size 'M'), then I need to show the selected attributes by the customer in the cart page and order pages also.

I have created an attribute of type multi-option, how can I manage this?

I checked this [AbstractOption](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractOption) But this needs to be specified by a customer when they add the item to their basket. In oscar, I used these options, it was giving an input type text box, where the customer has to put the value.

what I have done is I have created an attribute of type "Multi Option" named "size", this option is linked to a product class as an attribute. Now in size I created multi options say [S,M,L,XL], now I want users to be able to select a size from the product detail page. and i want to store this selected size by the user in the DB and show the selected choice in the cart and order detail pages. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't use attributes for this - you need to use product [options](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/apps/catalogue.html#oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models.AbstractOption) for options that a user can choose from.

Comment: @solarissmoke Updated my question, please check and help me with your guidance.